# HTMLUNIT , JAVA

Tags: java, htmlunit

I can not get a javascript response from the page.
FOLLOW MY CODE ...
jquery incompatible?

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_52);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
     webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
     webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(3000);
     webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(3000);
     webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);

     HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("");
         HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm) page.getElementByName("tabview-consultas-publicas:formExtratos");
        HtmlRadioButtonInput radioButton = (HtmlRadioButtonInput) form.getRadioButtonsByName("tabview-consultas-publicas:formExtratos:tipoInformacao").get(0);      
        radioButton.setAttribute("checked","");
        radioButton.setChecked(true);
        HtmlButton button = form.getButtonByName("tabview-consultas-publicas:formExtratos:j_idt156");
        button.click();
        System.out.println(page.asText());
        System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Hi Frederico, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you describe the problem in more detail?

Comment: I'm browsing a page .jsf
in the page I have a select radio and a button ... when clicking the button it should give me a javascript return without updating a page ... however it does not return anything .. just the current page.

Comment: Please update your question with that description, and any other information that >>you<< think will help us to help you.  An MCVE is advisable.  And ... please don't **SHOUT** at us.

Answer (score 0):

it is really hard to give you some advice based on the information you provided. At least there is no url to give us a chance to reproduce your problem and you told us nothing about any log output.

So here my rought suggestions:

- use the latest HtmlUnit version or even better the latest snapshot build
- use the most recent browser simulation (at the moment FF62)
- do not set any option if you do not need (and understand) what they are doing
- waitForBackgroundJavaScript() is not an options (as mentioned several times here) you have to call this after an action

No regarding button clicking; as of today there are more or less three kind of buttons

1. the good old plain submit button. This kind of buttons are submitting some form to the server and you will get back a new page. To work with this you have to use the result of the click method like nextPage = button.click();
2. the html button tag that does some javascript magic with you current page. In this case you can ignore the result of the click() method and proceed with the page you already have. The execution of the javascript might be async, to deal with this you have to call webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(3000); after the click() call
3. the fancy ajax based super clever action processing done these days by all this js frameworks out there. This is usually a enhance version of 2 - the difference might be that the page is replaced (reloaded) triggered from javascript. If this reload happens, you page object (and also the result of the click method) will point to the old page. To handle this case you have to do something like this

> ```
> btn.click();
> // wait for the async js
> webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(20000);
> // get the current page from the window in case it was replaced by some js magic
> newPage = (HtmlPage) page.getEnclosingWindow().getTopWindow().getEnclosedPage();
> ```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you.
I do not speak English because of this my question was confused